# joda dateTime, get duration in range

Tags: java, jodatime

I use joda in my Java application.
I have four DateTime objects, e.g.:

```
a: from 2018/01/07 06:00 until 2018/01/07 07:00 (6:00 - 07:00)

b: from 2018/01/07 06:40 until 2018/01/07 11:25 (6:40 - 11:25)
```

And I need the Duration where **a** is in **b** - in this case **0:20**.
Is there a way to do this in a simple way with joda?

Comment: not 0:20 will be the answer  to your example ?

Comment: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html#overlap(org.joda.time.ReadableInterval), http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractInterval.html#toDuration()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Duration result = 
    new Interval(aStart, aEnd).overlap(new Interval(bStart, bEnd)).toDuration();
```